# Isolate Voice and Reduce Ambient Sounds

Tags: audio, midi, noise-reduction

I am trying to record voice anywhere. That is why I need a way to isolate the voice and reduce ambient sounds such as cars or trains. Ideally I want to do this with an iPhone, which does not have a high quality microphone.

Comment: Is it possible to control the mic gain of the iPhone? Be it native or with an app? Then you could turn the gain down and keep your voice source very close to the mic, this should reduce ambient sounds. Could you also add *what* you're recording exactly? Is it someone singing? Talking? Shouting? I can imagine that this matters for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a portable sound-booth, a good pop-filter and record very close to the mic.

Commerical portable sound-booth:
http://www.editorskeys.com/us/portable-vocal-booth-incl-free-mic-stand/

There are a bunch of DIY sound-booths you can build yourself at a low price:
https://startpage.com/do/search?q=diy+portable+sound-booth